# Why does Angular Material2 examples have everything in sidenav container?

Tags: angular-material2

Looking at the examples in [angular-material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) the apps are built inside an `md-sidenav-container` such as [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/70bd5fc20e7fe6b1749b334d29e842cb3681609d/src/demo-app/demo-app/demo-app.html). Why is this? 
A sidenav is a panel which is used for sidenav functions- not a container for the whole app.

Comment: It is just related to user experience. They are using the `md-sidenav-container` so that links to different material components are displayed as a list, and are accessible all the times. The user doesn't have to go back and forth in that way.

Comment: Not really - the sidenav could have just been a list of [`navItems`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/70bd5fc20e7fe6b1749b334d29e842cb3681609d/src/demo-app/demo-app/demo-app.html#L4) and the [`router-outlet`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/70bd5fc20e7fe6b1749b334d29e842cb3681609d/src/demo-app/demo-app/demo-app.html#L45) could have been outside the container

Comment: yes, but they want to hide that panel and give maximum visibility to the router contents.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear...but I am asking why do they have `<router-outlet>` inside a panel element - the sidenav. `<router-outlet>` isn't part of the `<md-sidenav>` which is being hidden with the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the sidenav container wraps both the sidenav and the content that will be possibly covered by the sidenav. This is especially the case when the sidenav is in fullscreen mode, i.e. sidenav has a height of 100%. If you don't insert the components into the sidenav-container they will be shown below or above the sidenav.

Please take a look at the documentation for the [sidenav component](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview).